# How to show unreachable messages when using fping

Tags: ping

I am using fping to ping several devices from a text file and export the info into another file.

```
fping -lDf IPlist >IPoutput
```

This works, "Host unreachable messages" however do not get exported into the file, only successful pings.

However I would want to catch those too, how can I make fping to do that?

(CentOS 7)

ping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error messages are usually outputted into *standard error output*, or stderr. It is intentionally separate from regular *standard output*.

To redirect both regular output and errors to a file, do:

```
fping -lDf IPlist >IPoutput 2>&1
```